# SyntaxError: syntax error in ajaxFileUpload jquery plugin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i want to pass other parameters with file to save in database.when i put code to get those variables and save in database it give me alert "SyntaxError: syntax error"...
here is my code

```
$.ajaxFileUpload
    ({
    url:'popup/doc_mydeal.php',
    secureuri:false,
    fileElementId:'deals_documents',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{rand_key: $('#rand_key').val(), document_name: $('#document_name').val()},
    success: function (data, status)
            {
     if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')
                {
                if(data.error != '')
                {
                 alert(data.error);
                 }
             }
            },
            error: function (data, status, e)
            {
                alert(e);
            }
        })
```

Now on doc_mydeal.php

```
$tempFile = $_FILES['deals_documents']['tmp_name'];
$targetFile=$path.$_REQUEST['rand_key'].basename($_FILES['deals_documents']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
```

and here is mysql query to save in database

Comment: Any errors on the PHP side?

Comment: error in php , js, or somewhere else?

Comment: Your dataType is `json` but you don't return anything.

Comment: No the same code is working for some time...but some time it give me alert(in javascript) saying "SyntaxError: syntax error"

Comment: here is what i return...echo "{";
 echo    "error: '" . $error . "',\n";
 echo    "msg: '" . $msg . "'\n";
 echo "}";

Comment: @Methew Use the `json_encode` function rather than trying to generate the correct JSON string yourself.

Comment: Your json is invalid use `json_encode` to generate the json for you also see http://json.org/ to see how to manually generate json.

Comment: how to return file name only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify a `dataType` of `json` in the options for the jQuery AJAX call you're telling the code that the server will be returning valid JSON. Based on this information jQuery will implicitly parse the response text as JSON, passing the resulting object as the argument of the callback function.

In the case that the response text *isn't* valid JSON the parse will fail and the `error` callback will be executed instead. As has been pointed out in the comments, what you're returning from your PHP script is invalid JSON.

Comment: but why my data is not saved in mysql table? formating json and returning it is executed later!!

Comment: i just want to return filename..what i should do on both sides?